# Jquery UI accordion question - how would you approach this?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI accordion control in one of my apps asp.net apps. The data for the accordion comes from a database, and each database record has an ID, a Title Field and a content field. The title is the heading, and the content is the data that shows up when the draw is opened...

I'd like to be able to call my page like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage.aspx?ID=123
```

and have it display all the data (as it does now), but then have the default 'drawer' of the accordion open to the section that corresponds to the ID number passed in on the url...there are about 50 sections on the page.

Any suggestions on how to approach this? My questions is specific to the jquery accordion function, the rest I know. So where would be the best place to 'tag' the drawer with the unique ID's, and then what is the snippet of javascript code (I assume) that I would use 'open' that drawer based on the ID passed in??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly modified version the example file you get when downloading a custom JQuery UI build at http://jqueryui.com/download with only "core" and "accordion" selected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){

                // Accordion
                $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });

                // can be done somewhere later in the code, after init
                $('#accordion').accordion('activate' , "#a2");              
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 class="demoHeaders">Accordion</h2>
        <div id="accordion">
            <div>
                <h3 id="a1"><a href="#">First</a></h3>
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3 id="a2"><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
                <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3 id="a3"><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
                <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the selector-argument have to match the element you specified as "header" - in this example it is the H3-Tag, which got the ID. Running this code should open the second pane. Anoher way is, to specify the active pane in the init using the "active" option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){    
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", active :"#a2"  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I asume you have some HTML like this (I put the ID in the A-Tag):

```
<div id="accordion">
  <div>
    <a id="a1" href="#">First header</a>
    <div>First content</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a id="a2" href="#">Second header</a>
    <div>Second content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and you activate the Accordion like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

The Accordion provides a method to activate a specific pane:

> Activate a content part of the
>   Accordion programmatically. The index
>   can be a zero-indexed number to match
>   the position of the header to close or
>   a Selector matching an element. Pass
>   -1 to close all (only possible with collapsible:true).

so you can use:

```
$("#accordion").accordion("activate", "a#a2");
```

to activate it via script.

Comment: In theory it should work....I cannot get it to work using a string as a selector no matter now many variations I try...what cersion of jqueryui are you using?

Comment: This was with jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js and jquery-1.3.2.min.js
I would love the attach an example file... I will post a working example right away...

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$("#accordion").accordion('activate' , 1);
```

where 0 would be the first drawer, 1 the second and so on.